# opengl texture cube c++

Tags: c++, opengl, cube

hello i create a cube and want on one side an texture.

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, filterMode);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, filterMode);

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);   //Vorderseite
    glColor4f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f); //ROT
    glVertex3f(-fSeitenL/2.0f,-fSeitenL/2.0f,+fSeitenL/2.0f);
    glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f); //GELB
    glVertex3f(+fSeitenL/2.0f,-fSeitenL/2.0f,+fSeitenL/2.0f);
    glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f); //WEISS
    glVertex3f(+fSeitenL/2.0f,+fSeitenL/2.0f,+fSeitenL/2.0f);
    glColor4f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f); //MAGENTA
    glVertex3f(-fSeitenL/2.0f,+fSeitenL/2.0f,+fSeitenL/2.0f);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

but i can't see my texture, what did i wrong?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this doesn't seem a cube but just a *quad*, a cube is made by 6 different *quads*.. (and you could use `GL_QUADS` instead that `GL_POLYGON`.

Second thing is that you are loading the texture but not mapping it to the vertices. You need to supply coordinates to map how the texture should fit onto the quad. You can do it by using

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
```

the example is taken from **NEHE** OpenGL guide and I really suggest you to take a look since it's quite well explained: http://nehe.gamedev.net

Check tutorial 6 about texture mapping: http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06

Answer (score 4):

You haven't supplied texture coordinates. You need to issue one call to `glTexCoord` (the `2f` variant being the most commonly-used) that indicates a part of the texture that the vector maps to, *before* the corresponding `glVertex` call.

Otherwise, OpenGL has no idea how the texture should be pasted onto the polygons.